# What's the best way to re-process HTML into a single-line string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm working on a WordPress plugin that exports posts and associated data into a tab-seperated text format. It's almost finished, but I'm struggling to find the best method to re-process HTML into single strings.

I'm using a combination of preg_replace and htmlentities, but it's getting a little messy.

I'm sure there must be a preferred method for doing this, so I thought I would check with you? I can't find anything suitable on Google.

Comment: Not sure what do you need in result? Can you please specify sample input and expected output?

Comment: You're trying to turn multi-line text into single-line so it won't break your tab-delimited CSV? Other than fixing up entities and `preg_replace('/[\t\r\n]*/', ' ', ...);` there shouldn't be too much to it. The biggest problem with building CSVs is handling the metacharacters (tabs, commas, quotes).

Comment: It's all a bit of a mess at the moment. I was just wondering if there was a preferred PHP technique for squeezing HTML code into a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no single sure fire way but some simple regex would do the trick:

```
// remove convert newlines and multiple spaces into 1 space
$html = preg_replace("/\s+|\n+|\r/", ' ', $html);
```

Comment: OK, guess I'm on the right track then. Thank for the confirmation and comments!

Comment: `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n]`.

Comment: What's the point behind regexp? I mean in this case it's just a huge overhead (replacing characters using regexp?!)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered base64 encoding?

```
$foo = base64_encode($data);
```